# Why does my statefull widget not rebuild properly after setState() in flutter?

Tags: flutter, state

I have a statefull widget 'Dialogue' that gets an 'Event' from its parent. This Event has an initStateID and then many other states. I am trying to cycle through theese states using the setState() function to change the property '_currentState' of the statefull widget 'Dialogue'.

The state should change when I click a button. The console prints the following lines:

printing details...

> I/flutter ( 5101): current state id: 10011  I/flutter ( 5101): next
>   id: 10010  I/flutter ( 5101): new state id: 10010  I/flutter ( 5101):
>   current state id: 10010

But the widget tree does not change. I have even made a '_helpfunction' and assigned it to the 4th button. When I click it after the setState() is called, the _currentState is back to 10011.

> I/flutter ( 5101): currentstateid: 10011

It seems to me that whenever I trigger the rebuild function the '_currentState' sets itself back to the initState. How can I solve this?
I have been trying for many hours so thanks for any help!

Here is the code:

```
    class Encounter extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _State createState() => _State();
}

class _State extends State<Encounter> {
  Event _currentEvent;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _currentEvent =
        DataStorage.events[new Random().nextInt(DataStorage.EVENTCOUNT)];

    return Dialogue(firstEvent: _currentEvent);
  }
}

class Dialogue extends StatefulWidget {
  Dialogue({Key key, this.firstEvent}) : super(key: key);
  Event firstEvent;
  @override
  _DialogueState createState() => _DialogueState();
}

class _DialogueState extends State<Dialogue> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    EventState _currentState = (DataStorage.eventStates
        .singleWhere((f) => f.id == widget.firstEvent.initStateID));

    void _helpfunction(ButtonData data) {
      print("currentstateid: ${_currentState.id}");
    }


    void _advance(ButtonData data) {
      print('printing details...');
      print("current state id: ${_currentState.id}");
      print("next id: ${data.nextID}");

      final _newState = (DataStorage.eventStates.singleWhere((f) => f.id == data.nextID));
      print("new state id: ${_newState.id}");
      setState(() {
        _currentState = _newState;
        print("current state id: ${_currentState.id}");
      });
      //tady se muze delat cokoli s informacema od ButtonData
    }

    return SafeArea(
        child: Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            widget.firstEvent.personName,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 26,
              color: Colors.black,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              decoration: TextDecoration.none,
            ),
          ),
          Image.asset(
            widget.firstEvent.imagePath,
            height: 300,
          ),
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
                border: Border.all(width: 2.0, color: Colors.black)),
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              child: Text(
                _currentState.sentence,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Table(
            defaultVerticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
            children: [
              TableRow(
                children: [
                  ReactionButton(
                    source: _currentState.butt1,
                    advance: _advance,
                  ),
                  ReactionButton(
                    source: _currentState.butt2,
                    advance: _advance,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              TableRow(
                children: [
                  ReactionButton(
                    source: _currentState.butt3,
                    advance: _advance,
                  ),
                  ReactionButton4(
                    source: _currentState.butt4,
                    helpfunction: _helpfunction,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Reaction Button:

```
class ReactionButton extends StatelessWidget {
  ReactionButton({Key key, this.source, this.advance}) : super(key: key);
  final Function advance;
  final ButtonData source;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
      child: FlatButton(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: Text(
          source.text,
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          advance(source);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The ReactionButton4 is similar but calls the '_helpfunction' when tapped.

This is what my stored data look like:

```
static List<Event> events = [
    Event(
      id: 100,
      personName: 'Batman',
      imagePath: 'images/batman.png',
      initStateID: 10011,
    ),
    Event(
      id: 101,
      personName: 'Kocka',
      imagePath: 'images/kocka.jpg',
      initStateID: 10110,
    ),
  ];

  static List<EventState> eventStates = [
    EventState(
      id: 10010,
      sentence: "sentence",
      butt1: ButtonData(text: '1', nextID: 10011),
      butt2: ButtonData(text: '2', nextID: 10011),
      butt3: ButtonData(text: '3', nextID: 10011),
      butt4: ButtonData(text: '4', nextID: 10011),
    ),
    EventState(
      id: 10011,
      sentence: "?!?!?",
      butt1: ButtonData(text: 'a', nextID: 10010),
      butt2: ButtonData(text: 'b', nextID: 10010),
      butt3: ButtonData(text: 'c', nextID: 10010),
      butt4: ButtonData(text: 'd', nextID: 10010),
    ),
    EventState(
      id: 10110,
      sentence: "Mnau1",
      butt1: ButtonData(text: '1', nextID: 10111),
      butt2: ButtonData(text: '2', nextID: 10111),
      butt3: ButtonData(text: '3', nextID: 10111),
      butt4: ButtonData(text: '4', nextID: 10111),
    ),
    EventState(
      id: 10111,
      sentence: "Mnau2",
      butt1: ButtonData(text: 'a', nextID: 10110),
      butt2: ButtonData(text: 'b', nextID: 10110),
      butt3: ButtonData(text: 'c', nextID: 10110),
      butt4: ButtonData(text: 'd', nextID: 10110),
    ),
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You reset your `_currentState` variable on each rebuild. After calling `setState`, the Widget is automatically rebuilt. So you correctly set your `_currentState` variable, but as soon as the `build` functions is called, it is reset to the initial state.

You have to get the variable out of your build function and have to set it e.g. in the `initState` function of the class. Try the following change on the `Dialogue` class

```dart
class Dialogue extends StatefulWidget {
  Dialogue({Key key, this.firstEvent}) : super(key: key);
  Event firstEvent;
  @override
  _DialogueState createState() => _DialogueState();
}

class _DialogueState extends State<Dialogue> {
  EventState _currentState  

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _currentState = (DataStorage.eventStates
        .singleWhere((f) => f.id == widget.firstEvent.initStateID));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    void _helpfunction(ButtonData data) {
      print("currentstateid: ${_currentState.id}");
    }
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you!
Your suggestion works!
I have also tried some initState magic but ended up trying to define the variable _currentState twice. Once in initState and once in the state build function as I was confused.

Comment: @VláďaHořký is my answer working for you, then please accept it with the check mark on the post. Thx